# setstretch and todonotes

Tags: line-spacing, todonotes, setspace

I'm attempting to use the `todonotes` package to make margin annotations connected to points in a text. In order to give more space for the annotations, I'd like to be able to increase the line spacing of the main text without increasing the spacing inside the notes. I've used `setspace` to set the line spacing, but placing an additional `\setstretch` command inside the `\todo` command has no effect at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{1.7}

\begin{document}

This is a long text that goes onto two lines. \todo{\setstretch{1.0} This is a longish note about the text.} I'm not sure what else to put here because I need form and not content but form has to have content.

\end{document}
```

[image: the result of the above code]

How can I go about setting line spacing independently inside notes? Have I misunderstood something about `setspace`, or is there a different package I should be using, or something?

(I've seen the solution to this problem for `fixme`, but it involves a parameter which `todonotes` doesn't seem to have.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing `\selectfont` after `\setstretch{1}`.

In order to avoid having to type in `\setstretch{1}\selectfont` in every note, you can abuse the `size` key:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{1.7}
\presetkeys{todonotes}{size=\setstretch{1}\selectfont}{}

\begin{document}

This is a long text that goes onto two
lines.\todo{This is a longish note about the text.}
I'm not sure what else to put here because I need
form and not content but form has to have content.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! That solves the problem!

Comment: If I do this, I get `Undefined control sequence. \presetkeys` and if I then load `xkeyval` package, then I get the error `Package xkeyval Error: `uniquename' undefined in families `blx@opt@name'. ...`. What am I missing? I don't understand the error. `xkeyval` thinks I am misspelling `uniquenames`, but I am not spelling uniquenames at all. Should I open a new question about it do you happen to recognize what happened there?

Comment: @thymaro This has to do with `biblatex` and appears to be unrelated to the present problem.

Comment: ah, ok, thx. I'll toss out `xkeyval` and `\presetkeys` then and leave the todo notes stretched as they are.

Answer (score 0):

To allow for single line spacing and so it works with my biblatex, I defined a new command as redefining it is a little more complex.

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\todo[]{\linespread{1}\footnotesize #1 \par}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way out (adapted from an answer posted in [9-to-5-Science](https://9to5science.com/how-can-i-set-single-spacing-in-todonotes) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[color=blue!10, 
            linecolor=blue!60!gray,
            textsize=footnotesize]
           {todonotes}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch{1.7}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{%
    \@todo[caption={#2}, #1]{\begin{spacing}{0.85}#2\end{spacing}}%
} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

This is a long text that goes onto two lines.
\todo{This is a longish note about the text.}%
I'm not sure what else to put here because I need
form and not content but form has to have content.

\end{document}
```

Added a pinch of different colour and line-break aesthetics...
producing the following (presumably pleasing) output :

[image: output-image]